# missing values in a floating point matrix OpenCV

Tags: opencv, floating-point, missing-data, mat

I want to reconstruct missing values in a floating point matrix in OpenCV. The Mat contains floating values with minimum value 0.
I tried this :

1. Convert floating point Mat to CV_8U . The CV_8U image when displayed (points with 0 in floating Mat appear as black):

   [image: floating Mat to image]
2. Generate a mask by checking 4-neighborhood for atleast one non zero pixel with current pixel being zero. **Mask depicts pixels to be reconstructed**(255-missing pixels and  0-otherwise) The mask is :

[image: mask]

1. Used [inpaint function](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/photo/doc/inpainting.html) with image obtained in step 1 and mask from step 2. The inpainted result :

[image: inpainted result]

Now I have pixel values at missing locations(above image) but this inpaint cannot be directly applied to floating point Mat. It accepts only 8-bit 1-channel or 3-channel image. **How can I reconstruct/obtain missing values in the floating point Mat ?**

Answer (score 0):

If losing precision from the float-uchar conversion is acceptable across the entire image, you can do:

```
cv::Mat result;
inpainted_image.convertTo(result, CV_32F);
```

If you only want to fill in the missing values, do the above and then transfer the `result` values where your mask is nonzero.